# Quick way to get current opened filename in a script?

Tags: scripting, python

I'm looking for an efficient way to get the current `.blend` file name, in a python script.

I know how to get its path, with `bpy.path.abspath('//')`, but it returns only the current path, without the file name. I'm sure it's possible, but I can't find out how.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's in [`bpy.data.filepath`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.filepath).

This is the absolute path to the currently open blend file, see [`is_saved`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendData.html?highlight=is_saved#bpy.types.BlendData.is_saved), and [`is_dirty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendData.html?highlight=is_dirty#bpy.types.BlendData.is_dirty) too.

Answer (score 24):

You can get the filename with `bpy.path.basename(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath)`. This will return it as a string without the path attached. *Use for Windows compatibility and some more info [here](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bpy.path.html).*

Answer (score 0):

If you run Python script directly from a Unix Shell with a Blender as interpreter you may use one of below:

```
#!blender -P
import os,sys

print("OS.PATH.ABSPATH(__FILE__): "+ os.path.abspath(__file__))
print("SYS.ARGV[-1]: " + sys.argv[-1])
```

[`os.path.abspath(__file__)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) will give you an absolute path (`relpath()` available as well).

[`sys.argv[-1]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) will give you a relative path.