# How to set render filepath using blend filename in python

Tags: python

Let say I have blend file called **test01.blend**, then I want to automatically assign render filepath via python to `/media/data/render/[current blend filename]/[current blend filename]_`.

So, it should look like this `/media/data/render/test01/test01_`

I'm trying to access it via `bpy.data.filepath`, but I got only full file path for current blend file not blend file name.

Thanks for your help

Comment: See this [post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/quick-way-to-get-current-opened-filename-in-a-script)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [iKlsR's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2548/599):

> You can get the filename with
>   `bpy.path.basename(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath)`. This will return
>   it as a string without the path attached.

You can then assign the render output path with it:

```
import bpy

filename = bpy.path.basename(bpy.data.filepath)
if filename:
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = filename
```

Note that basename will include the file extension (`.blend`). You can strip it using [`os.path.splittext()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

```
import os
import bpy

filename = bpy.path.basename(bpy.data.filepath)
filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

if filename:
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = os.path.join("/media/data/render", filename, filename + "_")
```

Comment: is there any difference between `bpy.context.blend_data.filepath` and `bpy.data.filepath`?

Comment: it'll print .blend also in render filepath, any workaround to solve this?

Comment: @aditia Added a workaround

Comment: @CoDEmanX Good question. I don't know, but I don't see any.. (perhaps you should ask it? ;) )

Comment: @gandalf3 your workaround solve my issue, thanks a lot

Comment: maybe make it more generic and use `os.path.splitext[0]` instead of `replace('.blend', '')`?

Comment: Yes, IMHO `os.path.splitext(filename)[0]` is cleaner. There's always a possibility that `.blend` is embedded within the file's basename, though of course it's bad naming.