# Blender Python based on file path rendering

Tags: python, rendering

I can pass  [Command Line Rendering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/advanced/command_line/render.html) Render `.blend` files based on paths.

`blender -b "file path" -a`

Next, I want to try doing it via bpy, I can render the current scene via `bpy.ops.render.render()`, but how do I get Blender Python to render the .blend file in the path?

```
import bpy 

file_path = '/BlenderRenderScript_Test/model/02.blend'
```

Thank you for your help。

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own yet? or is this all the code you've managed to write?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can render the current scene using `bpy.ops.render.render()` but don't know how to render the files in the path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set render filepath using blend filename in python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3738/how-to-set-render-filepath-using-blend-filename-in-python)

Comment: I tried googling 'blender render from file path' and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3738/how-to-set-render-filepath-using-blend-filename-in-python) was the first result. Make sure you try to do a minimum of research on the subject before asking questions, that way we can make sure there's not 50 of the same question clogging up the forum unneccessarily. If you try this and still run into issues, and can't find answer to those issues then come back and post again with a more specific issue.

Comment: I've also seen this answer, which talks about breaking up file paths, and doesn't explain anything about rendering.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075599/opening-blend-files-using-blenders-python-api) one.

Comment: @jakemoyo Thank for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking, in effect, "How can I open a new blend file from the currently running Blender instance and then continue running commands from the same script?"

The answer is "*You can't*".  You can do the first part, opening an new blend file using

```py
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath="file path")
```

but as soon as you do that your current script will stop running and Blender will do exactly what it would have done if you hit the "Open" entry in the File menu: start over with the new file.

Comment: Thanks for you help!I wrote a python script that iterates over multiple blender files and executes render(`blender -b "file path" -a`) commands in sequence.
But this method is not friendly to people who are not familiar with programming, so I want to traverse multiple blender files through bpy and execute related commands in sequence.

my plan:
1. Internal functions of Blender;
2. Create an easy-to-operate GUI interface;
Excuse me, does bpy support the practice of traversing multiple files and executing related commands in sequence?