# How to get the directory of open blend file? (from Python)

Tags: python

What's the best way to get the full directory of the current Blender file in Python?

It should be cross-platform.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/quick-way-to-get-current-opened-filename-in-a-script

Comment: @stacker, I was hoping for something cleaner. Both Adhi and iKIsR's answers would return the whole filepath including filename.  I'd have to split the string using '/' for Linux/Mac and '\\', then strip it off the end.  Is there not a single command to get the directory?

Comment: Python as well as Blender provide path util functions, you shouldn't ever split using `/` and `\\`. Or at least use `os.path.sep` to get the separator for the current platform. But keep in mind Blender's own notation for relative paths (starting with `//`). And always check windows compatibility, python may fail for paths which are directly on a drive (drive missing the colon or the backslash).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Path Utilities module](https://docs.blender.org/api/latest/bpy.path.html) provides [`bpy.path.abspath("//")`](https://docs.blender.org/api/latest/bpy.path.html#bpy.path.abspath) where the "//" prefix is a Blender specific identifier for the current blend file.

You can also do...

- `bpy.path.abspath("//my/file.txt")`
- `bpy.path.abspath("//my\\file.txt")` on *Windows*, with backslash escaped
- `bpy.path.abspath(r"//my\file.txt")` on *Windows*, using python raw string
- `bpy.path.abspath("//../file.txt")`  to go back a directory

*This is used by all internal paths in blender, image, video, render, pointcache etc - paths. so blend files can reference paths relative to each file.*

Worth noting that the path may be an *empty string*, so you may want to check [`bpy.data.is_saved`](https://docs.blender.org/api/latest/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.is_saved) first.

Comment: you missed to escape the backslash, edited your answer to show two ways to handle them. General note: with raw strings, you can't have a `\ ` as last character, nor can you escape it like `\\ ` (will be used literally, as double backslash, `repr(r"\\")` gives `\\\\ `). *[had to add a space after \ for stackexchange]*

Comment: To get the correct separator character, you should use `os.path.sep`.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the functions provided by [os.path](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html) for handling pathnames independendly from a platform.

```
import bpy
import os

filepath = bpy.data.filepath
directory = os.path.dirname(filepath)
print(directory)
```

To add a file to the basename you could use os.path.join:

```
newfile_name = os.path.join( directory , "newfile.blend")
```