# How can I append an object from an external blender file using a relative path with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, path, append

[image: blender file path and contained]

How do I append a custom object from an external blender file using relative paths so I can pack the file with the addon? I can append the file easily with absolute path like this but I could fined how to do it with a relative path.

- external blender file path ---> D:\blend_folder
- blender file name ---> external_blender_file.blend
- object name ---> object_2

This is using an absolute path:

```
# import bpy
# bpy.ops.wm.append(filename="OBJECT_NAME", directory="/PATH/TO/BLENDFILE/NAME.blend\\Object\\")

import bpy
bpy.ops.wm.append(filename="object_2", directory="D:/blend_folder/external_blender_file.blend\\Object\\")
```

How to make it work with a relative path?

Comment: image did'not show

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a pretty nice example using [BlendDataLibraries](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html#module-bpy.types) and a relative path in the API: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html

Example script to append all objects named `Cube...` from a blend file called `link_library.blend` in the same folder as the script:

```
import bpy
import os

# "//" prefix is a Blender specific identifier for the current blend file
#filepath = "//link_library.blend"
#abs_filepath = bpy.path.abspath(filepath) # returns the absolute path

# os.path.abspath(__file__) returns path to the script
filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "link_library.blend")

# link all objects starting with 'Cube'
with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=False) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.objects = [name for name in data_from.objects if name.startswith("Cube")]

# link object to scene collection
for obj in data_to.objects:
    if obj is not None:
       bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)
```

Assuming the folder structure is like:

```
my_folder/
├── my_script.py
├── link_library.blend/
    ├── Objects
        ├── Cube
```

Further reading:

- [How do I get the full path of the current file's directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3430395)
- [How to Link/Append a data-block using the Python API?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/34540/31447)
- [How to get the directory of open blend file? (from Python)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6842/31447)

---

Can be wrapped into an operator easily. I suggest declare at least two [StringProperties](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.StringProperty), one to hold the *name of the blend* and another one for the actual *object name*, which basically allows to pass arguments when calling the operator or when adding the operator to any layout:

```
class MY_OT_custom_append(bpy.types.Operator):
    ...
    blend = StringProperty(name="Library Blend File")
    object_name = StringProperty(name="Object Name")
    ...

 # On a panel
 class MY_PT_custom_panel(Panel):
    ...
    row = layout.row()
    props = row.operator(MY_OT_custom_append.bl_idname)
    props.blend = "link_library.blend"
    props.object_name = "Cube"
    ...

...
# Test call
bpy.ops.scene.custom_append(blend="link_library.blend", object_name="Cube")
```

Read: [How to pass multiple operator properties via UI layout?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2515/31447)

---

#### `custom_append.py`

Panel and operator example to append *given/known objects* from another *blend file* next to the Add-on *(see the folder structure above)*:

[image]

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Custom Append Add-on",
    "description": "",
    "author": "",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "3D View > Tools",
    "warning": "", # used for warning icon and text in addons panel
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Development"
}


import bpy
import os

from bpy.props import StringProperty
from bpy.types import Panel, Operator

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Append Operator
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class MY_OT_custom_append(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "scene.custom_append"
    bl_label = "Custom Append Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    blend = StringProperty(name="Library Blend File")
    object_name = StringProperty(name="Object Name")

    def execute(self, context):   

        # os.path.abspath(__file__) returns path to the addon
        filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), self.blend)

        # -> Test whether the file exist
        if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
            self.report({'WARNING'},"{} does not exist".format(self.blend))
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        # link all objects starting with 'Cube'
        with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=False) as (data_from, data_to):
            data_to.objects = [name for name in data_from.objects if name == self.object_name]

        # -> Test whether the obejct exist
        if not data_to.objects:
            self.report({'WARNING'},"{} not found in {}".format(self.object_name, self.blend))
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        # link object to scene collection
        for obj in data_to.objects:
            if obj is not None:
                # Append to active collection
                active_coll = context.view_layer.active_layer_collection
                active_coll.collection.objects.link(obj)
                # Append to main collection
                # context.collection.objects.link(obj)

        return {'FINISHED'}


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Panel in Object Mode
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class MY_PT_custom_panel(Panel):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_my_panel"
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tools"
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        file_name = "link_library.blend"
        object_name_01 = "Cube"
        object_name_02 = "Sphere"

        row = layout.row()
        props = row.operator(MY_OT_custom_append.bl_idname, text="Append {}".format(object_name_01))
        props.blend = file_name
        props.object_name = object_name_01

        row = layout.row()
        props = row.operator(MY_OT_custom_append.bl_idname, text="Append {}".format(object_name_02))
        props.blend = file_name
        props.object_name = object_name_02

        layout.separator()

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Registration
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

classes = (
    MY_OT_custom_append,
    MY_PT_custom_panel
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Further reading: [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/31447)

Comment: what if I wanted to append-only  Material from a blend file

Comment: Is this some kind of serious question or just a statement @Rakeshchoudhary ?

Comment: it is a question and I wanted to know if I just wanted to append a material instead of an object.

Comment: Something like `data_to.materials = [name for name in data_from.materials if name.startswith("My_Mat")]` should do it @Rakeshchoudhary

Comment: I think i also need to replace this line `active_coll = context.view_layer.active_layer_collection
                active_coll.collection.objects.link(obj)` for material and if I replace it with `active_coll.collection.material.link(mat)` it gives error `Collection object has no attribute material`

Comment: Materials can not be linked to a collection... @Rakeshchoudhary